# Complicated XML with namespace for beginner

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I received an XML file from a client, and I have to reproduce it using C#.
I started today reading about XML files and I'm going anywhere :/ 
I'm using XMLDocument cause I read it was helpful and not so complicated.
Maybe you can help me guys to understand how to I get exprsions like:   to come as a root element.

```
<DeviceDescription>
<Types namespace="localTypes"/>
<Strings namespace="Unit">
    <Language lang="de-DE"/>
    <Language lang="en-EN"/>
</Strings>
<Strings namespace="localStrings_child_-1_1">
    <Language lang="de-DE">
        <String identifier="50">Drehmoment</String>
    </Language>
    <Language lang="en-EN">
        <String identifier="50">Torque</String>
    </Language>
</Strings>

<Files namespace="localFiles">
    <Language lang="en">
        <File fileref="local" identifier="NUM_ICO">
             <LocalFile>Motor.ico</LocalFile>
        </File>
    </Language>
</Files>
```

part of my code:

```
//Declaration of the XML Document
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
XmlNode declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UNICODE", null);
doc.AppendChild(declaration);

//Name of the Root
XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("DeviceDescription");
doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

//First Node "Types"
XmlNode typesNode = doc.CreateElement("Types");
XmlAttribute typesAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("namespace");
typesAttribute.Value = "localTypes";
typesNode.Attributes.Append(typesAttribute);
rootelement.AppendChild(typesNode);

//Second Node "Strings"
XmlNode strings1Node = doc.CreateElement("Strings");
XmlAttribute strings1Attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("namespace");
strings1Attribute.Value = "Unit";
strings1Node.Attributes.Append(strings1Attribute);
rootelement.AppendChild(strings1Node);

//Third Node "Strings"
XmlNode stringsNode2 = doc.CreateElement("Strings");
...

//Third Node "Files"
XmlNode priceNode = doc.CreateElement("Files");
...
```

I know it's everything wrong cause I can't compile it, maybe someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: What error messages do you get when you try to compile?

Comment: Different ones, I change and change my code, and comment and uncomment my lines, but I don't get even the line:  <Types namespace="localTypes"/>  It's really frustrating... Maybe it's better to start from the basics, cause for sure I'm not understanding how this works :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run this code to generate the items you want and see the output that is built into the console:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UNICODE", null);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
```

Code to generate the root element...

```
XmlElement rootelement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, 
                         "DeviceDescription", string.Empty);
doc.AppendChild(rootelement);

XmlNode typesNode = doc.CreateElement("Types");
XmlAttribute typesAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("namespace");
typesAttribute.Value = "localTypes";
typesNode.Attributes.Append(typesAttribute);
rootelement.AppendChild(typesNode);
```

Code to display the string formed...

```
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
Console.Read();
```

Console output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UNICODE"?><DeviceDescription><Types namespace="loc
alTypes" /></DeviceDescription>
Press any key to exit...
```